# Flutter App login No redirecting Android Flutter FCM getToken()

Tags: php, android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

After I enter the username and password show notification Successfully Logged in but No redirecting and stuck (and I use the website and App in localhost).

[image: the image of stuck notification]

This the code in the Flutter App

```
if (OtherConfig.USE_PUSH_NOTIFICATION) {
        final FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

        await _fcm.requestPermission(
          alert: true,
          announcement: false,
          badge: true,
          carPlay: false,
          criticalAlert: false,
          provisional: false,
          sound: true,
        );

        String? fcmToken = await _fcm.getToken();



        if (fcmToken != null) {
          print("--fcm token--");
          if (is_logged_in.$ == true) {
            // update device token
            var deviceTokenUpdateResponse = await ProfileRepository()
                .getDeviceTokenUpdateResponse(fcmToken);
          }
        }
      }

      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return Main();
      }), (newRoute) => false);
    }
  }
```

and this the code of the website

```
public function loginSuccess($user, $token = null)
    {

        if (!$token) {
            $token = $user->createToken('tokens')->plainTextToken;
        }
        return response()->json([
            'result' => true,
            'message' => translate('Successfully logged in'),
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
            'expires_at' => null,
            'user' => [
                'id' => $user->id,
                'type' => $user->user_type,
                'name' => $user->name,
                'email' => $user->email,
                'avatar' => $user->avatar,
                'avatar_original' => uploaded_asset($user->avatar_original),
                'phone' => $user->phone,
                'email_verified' => $user->email_verified_at != null
            ]
            
        ]);
    }
```

i try to add this code in website and not working

```
$user->createToken('tokens')->plainTextToken;

        $this->loginSuccess($user);
```

Comment: still not work after use the modify code . and i need to tell you something the app redirecting when i sign up but with login still stuck what can i do ?